# Pressure Boosting Pump Running Overcurrent

Tags: electrical-engineering, motors, pumps

I'm working on an industrial water re-circulating system that is having an overcurrent issue that is baffling everyone involved (design engineer/plumber/electrician/pump and motor Mfg).

The system recirculates water on 2 separate loops, and is fed by a large tank open to atmosphere. End-use pressure is ~80 @ 2-15GPM depending on how much the system is being used. The two loops are independently pressurized by 2 3-HP pressure boosting pumps, plumbed directly to the tank. The pumps are rated for 80 PSI @ ~30GPM, and each loop has a bypass valve capable of 75GPM max to allow a flow path if the end use systems are shut down.

Operationally, everything works fine... the pumps sound good and build pressure and achieve sufficient pressure and flow at point of use. No excess vibration or sounds from the pumps. The bypass valves have some flow through them but also sound fine. The pumps have sufficient head pressure due to tank gravity.

The issue is that the pumps continually draw to the service factor amperage regardless of the conditions of the system. The FLA of the motors is 3.99A and the SFA is 4.59. The motors continuously run at ~4.9-5A and trip the motor starters after ~8 hours of running. The outer case temperature gets to be ~210DegF after 3-4 hours of running.

The electrician believes he has sized the motor overload relay (which is what trips) appropriately because the motors are supposed to run at 3.99A and the motors are running at a higher current which is reducing life-span. The pump is bought as a unit but comes with a motor manufactured by a 3rd party. Motor mfg tech support says the electrician is right and the motor is not intended to run in these conditions. Pump MFG tech support says the motor **is** intended to run a ~4.9A so nothing is wrong. Pump tech support also mentioned they'd expect to see temps up to ~180F but aren't surprised by ~210F.

I'm at a loss for what to do/try next. Nothing points to the pumps being incapable in the task beyond the over current situation. A larger overcurrent device could be spec'd but all signs point to these motors burning out sooner rather than later. I'd think the pump MFG spec'd an undersized motor but they're insisting they didn't. I really don't know who to believe or what to try next.

Comment: What is the electrical feed to the motors? Figure system efficiency at about 40 to 45%. A quick and dirty check against the Grundfos sizing calculator produces the same sized motors. But using a variable speed - constant pressure pump would be preferable. Can you confirm pressures at the pump outlet and inlets? Can you confirm actual voltage on the motor? What is the temp of the water  being pumped? What is the temperature of the pump room? Can you post photos of the pump? What is the mfg's required NPSH?